# How far should one read into Megalgelin Zechus?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, maseches-shabbos

There is a concept called מגלגלין זכות על ידי זכאי וחוב על ידי חייב, that good things and bad things come via those who are fitting to be their messengers (Shabbos 32a).

How far should one read into this? If a mitzvah comes to one’s hands, or he misses an opportunity to sin, should he take it as a sign that Hashem is pleased with him? Conversely, if a sin comes to one’s hands, or he missed an opportunity to do a mitzvah, should he take it as a sign that Hashem is displeased with him? Or, in either case, should he not read anything of the sort into it?

Comment: If the sign you refer to is an indication of the future then the following verse applies:

[Devorim 18 (13)](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.18.13?lang=bi&with=Sforno&lang2=en)

תָּמִ֣ים תִּֽהְיֶ֔ה עִ֖ם ה׳ אֱלֹקֶיךָ׃
You must be wholehearted with the L-RD your G-d. 

Sforno says 
תָּמִ֣ים תִּֽהְיֶ֔ה, whole-hearted to the extent that you will not even try and gain information about future events except through an authentic prophet.

Comment: This goes without saying, but whatever you do for yourself you should NEVER apply things like this to other living people and conclude that they're reshaim.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok as I read it the question isn't about future events.  It's about should you conclude that you're a זכאי/חייב.

Comment: and @Heshy after you have reached that conclusion what do you do differently compared to before reaching the conclusion. That is my interest in the person's future.

Comment: Good question, but I think I should be clarified. The title says "how far" like there are different measures but the question is about "should I believe it at all".

Comment: How this statement is different from מצוה גוררת מצוה ועבירה גוררת עבירה? One who did a mitzvah is called זכאי and presented with an opportunity to do anothe and same with transgressions.

Comment: @AlBerko I never asked “should I believe it at all.” “How far should one read into this? ... should he take it as a sign...” Sounds like different measures to me. I don’t understand your problem. I also don’t see this as anything to do with מצוה גוררת מצוה by the same token. I think you completely misunderstood my question.

Comment: How do you say "How far should one read into this" in Hebrew?

Comment: @AlBerko האם זה סימן מן שמים שמעשי נכונים? Does that work for you?

Comment: Good then, maybe "לעולם יראה אדם עצמו כאילו חציו חייב וחציו זכאי" so any way you're half Zakkay and half Hayav. On the other hand, if the Gemmorah says so, why would you question it? The G. states a "fact"- shouldn't we accept it as a fact? if you miss a Mitzvah you're called חייב - what's the problem? BTW this statement says nothing about Hashem - is He please or displeased. The person is apparently in the state of זכאי or חייב (as I mentioned in the beginning) but there's nothing to do with Hashem.